# How to change order status in Woocommerce with my custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, methods, plugins

I want to know how to change order status in WooCommerce with my custom plugin not woocommerce's plugin.

```
function changeStatus($order_id)
{
   $order = wc_get_order($order_id);  
   $order->set_status('pending');
   $order->save();
}
```

If I use `wc_get_order()` function, I got that error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function wc_get_order()
```

How to include or require woocommerce wc_get_order() function in order to use properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

You should first check that woocommerce plugin is active before in your plugin like:

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
     // Your plugin code
}
```

Also you should NOT need to use this kind of function in your plugin, as you can get in your plugin code the `WC_Order` Object from a valid order ID and better use [`WC_Order` method `update_status()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.1.0/includes/class-wc-order.php#L317-L350) which already includes `save()` method.

You can also use `WC_Order` class checking before that the class exist *(and then set or update order status)* from a valid order Id, using:

```
if( class_exists('WC_Order') && $order_id > 0 ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    if ( is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) {
        // Set or update order status
        $order->update_status('pending'); // save() method is already included
    }
}
```

Related documentation: [WooCommerce Plugin Developer Handbook](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/create-a-plugin/)

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function wc_get_order()

Comment: @ManlaibayarAmgalanbaatar Updated with an alternative… You should also try to clarify your question giving more context and more related code as nobody can really help you with the provided code and information.